# Ontology and syntactic representation

Tags: rdf, ontology, protege

I need to ask wether there is away to model synonym/ border/ narrower and other syntactic elation in the protege??

I am thinking to create object propriety "name" and then create property for this such that has broader name and so on.

Any idea I would appreciate that.

Comment: just use SKOS vocabulary?